# Javascript static method in class defined inside global object

Tags: javascript, oop, class, static-methods

I know Javascript doesn't have classes in the same way that traditional OOP languages do and that a "class" definition such as the following, is merely a function object that can be used with the `new` keyword:

```
function MyClass(){
  this.a = function(){ /* Do something */ }; // Public function
  function b(){ /* Do something */ }; // Private function
}
```

What I'm wondering is, if I define a global object (to avoid polluting the namespace) and define my classes inside this object, can I define a static method for my class in a nicer way than this:

```
var MyObject = {
  MyClass: function(){
    this.a = function(){ /* Do something */ }; // Public function
    function b(){ /* Do something */ }; // Private function
  },
}
MyObject.MyClass.MyStaticMethod = function(){ /* Do something */ };
```

I was thinking something along the lines of defining `MyStaticMethod` inside the `MyClass` function scope - is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this:

```
var MyObject = {
    MyClass: function(){
        this.a = function(){ /* Do instance-y stuff */ };
        MyClass.MyStaticMethod = function(){ /* Do static-y stuff */ };
    }
}
```

but I think it's a bad idea. In general, I think it's better practice (because it's more readable) to define both static and instance methods OUTSIDE of the constructor. As in:

```
function MyClass() { /* Do initialization stuff */ }
MyClass.prototype.a = function() { /* Do instance-y stuff */ }
MyClass.MyStaticMethod = function() { /* Do static-y stuff */ }
```